# Open a audio file...("audio/wav") using intent

Tags: android

I Have Been Trying To Open A File using intent and FileProvider but app crashes when i try to open the file..Here's what i am doing...please help me out..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mCtx, String.valueOf(R.string.file_provider_authority), new File(mydata.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath()));
    mCtx.grantUriPermission(mCtx.getPackageName() , uri , Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setDataAndType(uri, "audio/wav")
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        Intent choose = Intent.createChooser(intent, "See..");
        mCtx.startActivity(choose);
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Clicked " + mydata.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch (
            ActivityNotFoundException e
            ){

    }


   }
```

}

```
I got following exception --------- beginning of crash
```

2018-12-18 09:13:40.173 25265-25265/my.uapp.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my.uapp.com, PID: 25265
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:605)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at my.uapp.com.MyAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(MyAdapter.java:73)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6320)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25087)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:869)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6749)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting...here's what i got in stack

Comment: That Exception suggests that the authority you're passing in the `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` call does not match what you've specified on the `<provider>` element in your manifest. Those must match exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... so the provider have to be same as in manifest declaration... ☺

Comment: Yes, the `String` you're passing as the second argument in `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` must exactly match what you have for the `authorities` attribute on the `<provider>` in your manifest. Check the value you have there against your `file_provider_authority` resource string.

Comment: Thank you.... Mike M. I edited my code... And here's it's working now... THANK YOU So much you are awesome... ☺️

Comment: Cheers... Thank you so much..